Multi focal photos
I'm approaching to photography and I know from lessons of image sensing (satellite datas from engineering school) that exist the multi-focus image fusion. A sort of post processing combining multiple images with different focal point in order to obtain a multi-focus image.
Since is post processing (probably does exist hardware or lenses doing the same thing automatically) I think some software does the work. Does anyone know which software I could use?

Yes, 'focus stacking' is a common technique these days.  My Canon camera has a burst mode over a range of focus distances specifically to be used with this technique. There are systems in Photoshop and other applications that can do this automatically, though they might be weirdly named.

Photoshop works perfectly! Thanks
